# Using javascript to get php/mysql values

Tags: php, javascript, android, mysql, titanium

i am thinking of building an android app in appcellerators titanium application, and i have a question, the website which the app is for is built using php/mysql, and what i am wondering is, as titanium works using javascript, html and css only, is there a way i can pull the data dynamically from my database using javascript?

if this has already been posted I'm sorry i searched and couldnt find it :S

Comment: Directly via JS - no. However, nothing prevents you from creating a service that your JS code talks to (receives data in JSON format from MySQL using PHP) which enables you to continue using titanium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PHP, take your database response array and encode it like this:

```
<?php
json_encode($db_array);
?>
```

More information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Note that you'll need PHP 5.2 or above in order to have the built in JSON functions for PHP.

In Titanium, you want to open a XHR (or network handler) to grab the data:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
var.onload = function()
{
   try
   {
      data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   }
   catch (excp)
   {
      alert('JSON parse failed');
   }

   // you should handle your network async, meaning you should handle any renders or any post elements here. if you make it sync, you'll cause all other handlers and functions to work improperly (like click events, etc).
}

xhr.open("GET", "your url here");
xhr.send();
```

You can access the the data array by simply calling data[0].some_col;

Answer (score 0):

Try reading tutorial about using SQLite databases in Titanium applications
I'm sorry it's for iPhone, but in basics the principle is the same

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-database-driven-tables-with-sqlite/
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-database-driven-tables-with-sqlite-part-2/
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-database-driven-tables-with-sqlite-%E2%80%93-part-3/

using is like this:

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('../products.sqlite','products');  
var rows = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT category FROM products');
```

Documentation:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.3/Titanium.Database-module

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use JSON using json_encode if you were accessing the database from the website. If you were trying to use a local database then use sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build an webservice on your website, and pull the data in with `Titanium.Network.HTTPClient`

You can see it here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object

An example would be:

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function() {
    var data = this.responseText; //response is here
    // do your thing within this scope, or call a function/event from here
}

var url = 'http://www.google.nl';
xhr.open("GET", url); // or "POST"
xhr.send();
```

Note that the data variable is not accessable outside the scope, even if it is a global. Call your function from within the scope

In the app you could either use SQLite, or don't store the data. Whatever suits your application best